# What is the origin of the quantifier symbols ∀ and ∃?

Tags: logic, notation, math-history

It's pretty natural how they stand for the phrases "For ∀ll" and "There ∃xists", but I was wondering who was the first to use these symbols, and if they had any related meaning before this use.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't verified these references myself, but according to [this](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Etom/history/set.html#:%7E:text=Intersection%20and%20union.,%2C%20%C2%A72%2B%C2%A75) site...

Existence (existential quantifier), $\exists$:

> Peano used the symbol for
> existence in volume II, number 1, of his Formulaire de mathematiques,
> which was published in 1897 (Cajori vol. 2, page 300).
>
> Kevin C. Klement writes, "While Peano had the backwards E for a
> predicate of classes, Russell was the first to use the backwards E as
> a variable binding operator, and there are the wonderful manuscripts
> printed in CPBR vol 4 in which Russell's makes large dots out of
> Peano's backwards epsilons to change over from the Peano-notation for
> existence to a more Fregean one."

For all, $\forall$:

> According to M. J. Cresswell and Irving H. Anellis, the letter A
> appearing upside-down originated in Gerhard Gentzen, "Untersuchungen
> ueber das logische Schliessen," Math. Z., 39, (1935), p, 178. In
> footnote 4 on that page, Gentzen explains how he came to use the sign.
> It is the "All-Zeichen," an analogy with the symbol for existence for
> the existential quantifier which Gentzen says that he borrowed from
> Russell.